# Trigger for not inserting more than one record

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am new in making triggers . I am using MYSQL 6.3 for my application.
I have a table structure as below

> ```
>     seriesid(pk) , modelid(fk) ,seriesname,  seriesactive
> ```

My requirement is like ,I should have only one record for each modelid which is in active state(yes).
my data is as below

> 1, modelid1, seriesname1, yes
>
> 2, modelid2, seriesname1, yes

I should not have another entry for modelid1, yes combination.
I am not able to develop a trigger for this scenario.

Could anyone please help me on this.

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Update your question with your attempted trigger code

Comment: Not sure why you need a trigger for that , would a unigue key on  modelid  seriesactive not work for you?

Answer (score 0):

A Idea to Implement this. Don't where you want to implement this but this will give a idea to how to implement this.

```
BEGIN   IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM your_table WHERE modelid = NEW.modelid 
AND seriesactive='yes') THEN
INSERT INTO your_table
  SET modelid1 = NEW.modelid,
      seriesname = NEW.seriesname,
             seriesactive = NEW.seriesactive;
END IF;
END
```